# Hi, I am trying to create a dataframe from a netcdf file, but I keep getting the following error message: cannot allocate vector of size 790.3 Mb

Tags: r

I'm unsure of how to allocate a different memory size to RStudio on my windows desktop. Any tips on what to do?
I have tried the memory function in R but this appears to be outdated on the latest version.
My code is as follows:

```
# Open the NetCDF file
ncfile <- nc_open("1990-1995.nc")

# List the variables available in the NetCDF file
print(ncfile$var)

# Read the data for a specific variable (replace "variable_name" with the actual variable name)
data <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "Sea surface temperature")

# Close the NetCDF file
nc_close(nc)

    print(paste("The file has",ncfile$nvars,"variables,",ncfile$ndims,"dimensions and",ncfile$natts,"NetCDF attributes"))

   attributes(ncfile$var)$names

    ncatt_get(ncfile, attributes(ncfile$var)$names[1]) # change number in [] to get each variable attributes

   varmatrix<- ncvar_get(ncfile, attributes(ncfile$var)$names[1])

    dim(varmatrix)

    lat <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "latitude")
    nlat <- dim(lat) #to check it matches the metadata
    lon <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "longitude")
    nlon <- dim(lon) # again to check

    time <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "time")
    head(time) # to have a look at the numbers in the time vector 
    tunits <- ncatt_get(ncfile, "time", "units") #check units
    print(tunits)
    nt <- dim(time) # should be the same as that listed in the meta data
#select variable
#extract sea surface temperature data
var_array <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "adjusted_sea_surface_temperature") 
    print(tunits)
#change to year/month/day format
   timesec<-(time*(60*60))
    time_obs<-as.POSIXct(timesec, origin="1900-01-01", tz="GMT")
#needs time to be in seconds not hours to uses timesec vector
    dim(time_obs)
    range(time_obs) # should be start and end of netcdf
#build the data frame
#create a 2D matrix of long, lat and time
    lonlattime<-as.matrix(expand.grid(lon,lat,time_obs))
    str(lonlattime)
```

Comment: It's not clear where in this code block you are experiencing the error. Also, please be explicit about non-base packages, I suspect it might be `ncdf4`.

Comment: Regardless, I suspect the use of `expand.grid` could be a problem: that creates a frame with `length(lon) * length(lat) * length(time_obj)` rows, doing a full cartesian expansion on all possible values. To me it doesn't necessarily make sense to create a row with `lon[1]` and all `lat` values, then `lon[2]` and all `lat` values again, ignoring the effect of `time_obj` ... what are you hoping to accomplish with the `expand.grid(.)` call?

Comment: Do you instead mean just `as.matrix(data.frame(lon, lat, time_obj))`?